# Problem with an inequality regarding a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inequality, logarithms

So, I have the following initial problem:
$y'(x) = \ln\ln(4+y(x)^2)$, $x\in[0,1]$

$y(0)=1$,
and I need to prove the following inequality:
$M_2=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|y''(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2e}$
As you can see by plotting the second derivative, this upper bound is as precise as it can be. I've tried calculating the third derivative, in an attempt to find it's root, and got nothing. Also, I couldn't get anything from using classic inequalities (ex $\frac{x}{x+1}\leq\ln(x)\leq x$)for the second derivative. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to calculate $y''$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
y''&=&\frac{[\ln(4+y^2)]'}{\ln(4+y^2)}\\
&=&\frac{2yy'}{(4+y^2)\ln(4+y^2)}\\
&=&\frac{2y}{4+y^2}\cdot\frac{\ln\ln(4+y^2)}{\ln(4+y^2)}\\
&=&g(y)h(\ln(4+y^2))
\end{eqnarray}

with
$$
g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto \frac{2t}{4+t^2},
$$
and
$$
h: [\ln4,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto \frac{\ln t}{t}
$$
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
g'(t)&=&2\frac{4+t^2-2t^2}{(4+t^2)^2}=\frac{2(4-t^2)}{(4+t^2)^2}\\
h'(t)&=&\frac{1-\ln t}{t^2}
\end{eqnarray}
It followa that $g$ is is decreasing on $(-\infty,-2)$ and $(2,\infty)$, and increasong on $(-2,2)$. Because
$$
\lim_{t \to \pm\infty}g(t)=0=g(0)
$$
we have
$$
|g(t)|\le |g(\pm2)|=\frac{1}{2} \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} 
$$
Furthermore, $h$ is increasing on $[\ln4,e)$ and decreasing on $(e,\infty)$.  Hence
$$
|h(t)\le h(e)=\frac{1}{e} \quad \forall t \ge \ln4 
$$
Hence
$$
\max_{0\le x\le 1}|y''(x)|=\max_{0\le x\le 1}|g(y(x))||h(\ln(4+y^2(x)))|\le \max_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|g(t)|\max_{s\ge \ln4}|h(s)|=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{2e}.
$$